# Trouble transitioning to multiprocessing python code to cython

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, cython

I'm running a program that takes real time data on a Raspberry pi 4. Because the program is quite demanding, the different functionalities are separated into the different cores with Multiprocessing using Pool, each process being an MQTT client.

I have been trying to transition the code to Cython but I have been running into trouble with multiprocessing. From posts I have seen on the internet, prange is used. But when trying to pass mqtt clients to prange I get errors concerning with nogil. Is there a way to use Pool with Cython or use multiple processes that require gil to run in parallel with Cython?

Sorry that it might sound like a newbie question, also I apologize but I can't show the code.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Edit:
Currently I'm stuck on the map section of Pool. Here is a code segment of it:

```
def clie1(num):
  global id1
  print("Clie1")
  mqttBroker="mqtt.eclipseprojects.io"
  id1 = os.getpid()
  client.on_connect = on_connect
  client.on_message = on_message
  client.connect(mqttBroker, 1883, 60)
  #client.connect("127.0.0.1", 1883, 60)
  client.loop_forever()


def clie2(num):
  global id2
  print("Clie2")
  mqttBroker="mqtt.eclipseprojects.io"
  id2 = os.getpid()
  client2.on_connect = on_connect2
  client2.on_message = on_message2
  client2.connect(mqttBroker, 1883, 60)
  #client2.connect("127.0.0.1", 1883, 60)
  client2.loop_forever()

def smap(f):
  return f()

client = mqtt.Client()
client2 = mqtt.Client()


def main():
  fc1 = functools.partial(clie1, 1)
  fc2 = functools.partial(clie2, 2)
  print("Pool")
  with Pool() as pool:
      res = pool.map(smap, [fc1,fc2])
        

main()
```

Terminal Result:

[image: Terminal Result]

My setup file is very simple and maybe it requires something additional to work:

```
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize("MyFile.pyx"),
)
```

Comment: "I apologize but I can't show the code." - the right thing to do is to strip it down to an [mre]. That can be minimal enough that you can omit any bits that are supposed to be secret.

Comment: But yes - `multiprocessing.Pool` should work with Cython. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes I have, my problem seems to be at the .map section, it does not seem to continue on.

I'll edit in a code segment.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This also looks to block for me if you run it as a py file rather than a Cython file (with a few basic fixes to your code, like imports...). I'm not sure what's wrong since I don't use multiprocessing that much but it doesn't immediately look like a Cython issue

Comment: Yeah to run it as a py file you need:

`'if __name__=="__main__":
    
    main()`

Instead of just main, I imagine this is where my issue is because when I try this in Cython it doesn't go to main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we've established the issue is that: to run it is a .py file you need

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

However a Cython file can't be run "as a script" so `__name__` is never `"__main__"`. (In principle this works with [embedded Cython](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/embedding.html) but I don't think that'll help you).

The solution is to write a tiny Python script that imports your Cython module and calls its `main()` function:

```
# Do NOT compile this script with Cython!
import my_cython_mod
if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_cython_mod.main()
```

When you do that a cut-down version of your example runs fine for me.

Comment: This worked! It also worked on my full code.

Thanks a lot for your help.